# Constructing a Mathematical Equation for Image Bands in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, image, gis, google-earth-engine, mathematical-expressions

I am struggling with an equation, getting some syntax error in it, The equation is following:
formula: `(K2 / ln ((K1/TOA_band10)+1)) - 273.15`

I am trying to do operation on image bands, but not being able to construct the right code.
I have used this instead:

```
var BT = band_10.expression((1329.2405*1.0/((799.0284*1.0/TOA_B10)+1).log10())-273.15)
```

But it did not work.

A general hint about constructing an equation in earth engine - javascript.

Comment: What about it didn't work? What was expected and what actually happened? Can you give a high-level description of what you're trying to achieve for those who aren't as familiar with your problem as you are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in the right direction. You have to include the `map` property of `expression()`. It defines the variables you can use inside your expression. Then with some minor tweaks to the actual expression, it works fine:

```
var BT = ee.Image().expression(
  '(K2 / log((K1 / TOA_band10) + 1)) - 273.15',
  {
    K1: 799.02841,
    K2: 1329.24051,
    TOA_band10: someImage
  }
)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e5cf09e87ddf51ec27a00b8ed4695ce4

Comment: Thank V Much  , appreciate it. ✌